# How to log database errors using Hibernate and Spring

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, interceptor, error-logging

So our app has like 10,000 different DAO classes using multiple session factories and data sources. The data sources use **c3p0** for connection pooling and we use **hibernate framework** to talk to an **oracle database**.

Now, when we have database errors like if the server is down, max connection attempts reached etc... We want to log them using **our own logging mechanism** basically do xxx.fatal("Database server down", e).

Question 1: How do I catch these exceptions? (Database server down, max connection attempts reached etc...)?

Question 2: How do I log by making minimal code changes? Can I use **hibernate interceptor** for this?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Spring AOP and create an `afterthrowing` advice to catch exceptions and log them. Have a look at [this](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/05/spring-aop-after-throwing-advice.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks Ean for ur reply. I started implementing this approach but I keep getting the error org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class

Comment: Complete error is this  Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser$AuthenticationManagerDelegator]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser$AuthenticationManagerDelegator

Comment: This should be related to your Spring's config. If you are using CGLIB as proxy provider, you need to enable it in configuration. I guess this is the problem (but not sure) ;)

Comment: My pointcut was using all the public methods and inturn was using a method from a jar and failing. Once I changed my pointcut I am not seeing the error anymore. I however am not getting the control to the aspect I have defined. I will post it in a diff question. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have added the problem I am facing using the @AfterThrows Advice in a seperate theread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386858/spring-aop-afterthrowing-advice-not-being-executed

Comment: A little bit busy today but will have a look at that one as well ;)